# Truncate the strings in a dataframe column using the integers present in another column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

Basically I'd like to perform a string manipulation on the elements in one column using another.

Here's some basic code to set up an example:

```
from random import seed,choices,sample,choice
from string import ascii_letters
import pandas as pd

seed(1)
strings = ["".join(choices(list(ascii_letters),k=4)) for i in range(10)]
values = [choice(range(4)) for i in strings]

df = {"strings":strings,"values":values}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

And here's the output:

[image]

I want to manipulate the choices column so that each entry is truncated using the values column.

So let's say we take the first entry for instance:

```
strings  values
  gSNn       2
```

The end result should be `"gSNn"[:2]` or simply `"gS"`

For the next entry, however:

```
strings  values
  zxHP       0
```

It would be `"zxHP"[:0]` or simply `""`

To try and accomplish this, I've tried the following:

```
df.loc[:,"strings"].str[:df.loc[:,"values"]]
```

However, the end result was this:

```
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   NaN
Name: strings, dtype: float64
```

I'm not too sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This operation cannot be used by passing Series, you need procesing it per rows in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: x["strings"][:x["values"]], axis=1)
```

Or in list comprehension:

```
df['new'] = [x[:y] for x, y in df[['strings','values']].to_numpy()]
```

---

```
print (df)
  strings  values  new
0    gSNn       2   gS
1    zxHP       0     
2    ebRw       2   eb
3    NaxL       3  Nax
4    lXUb       1    l
5    bCWt       2   bC
6    lvbl       2   lv
7    wzmm       3  wzm
8    lxpb       3  lxp
9    RCHj       0
```